# Are the two given lattices related to each other by a simple rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

I am trying to come up with a *general* algorithm to determine if two lattices are related to each other by a simple rotation operation.

The way I think about a **lattice** is as an array of points. The lattice is specified by a set of basis vectors. For example a 2D lattice can be defined by the following basis:

$$\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{b}_x & \vec{b}_y \end{bmatrix} $$

The lattice consists of all the points that can be expressed as integer linear combinations of the basis vectors: $l\vec{b}_x + m \vec{b}_y$, where $l,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. The lattice generated by the basis vectors $\vec{b}_x = \hat{e}_x + 2 \hat{e}_y$ and $\vec{b}_y = 5 \hat{e}_y$ is shown below.

[image]

Now suppose I am given two lattices with basis vectors as follows:

1. $\mathcal{B}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \Lambda_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$ and
2. $\mathcal{B}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \Lambda_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$.

The two lattices are shown next to each other.

[image]

I want to determine if **Lattice 2** is related to **Lattice 1** by a simple rotation **other than the identity operation**. I perform a few checks first:

1. I check that their volumes (determinants) are the same. Otherwise, they define two distinct lattices and so one lattice cannot be obtained by a simple rotation of the other.
2. I also check that $\Lambda_1^{-1} \cdot \Lambda_2$ is not a UNIMODULAR MATRIX (a matrix of integers with determinant $\pm$1). **If it is then the two bases define the same lattice**.
3. If they are related by a simple rotation, there exists a rotation matrix $\mathbb{R} \in O(3)$ such that $\Lambda_2 = \mathbb{R} \Lambda_1 U$, where $U$ is a unimodular matrix (i.e. a matrix of integers with $\det(U)=\pm 1$).

In the above example, I know visually that the two lattices are related to each other by a rotation operation. However, I am not sure how to solve it using a code of some sort. The complication I think comes from the fact that any lattice has infinitely-many bases.

**My solution:**
I assume a unimodular matrix with unknown integer entries $a,b,c,d$. I can use the properties of the rotation matrix (i.e. $\mathbb{R} \cdot \mathbb{R}' = I$, where $\mathbb{R}'$ is the transpose of the rotation matrix and $I$ is an identity matrix) and the unimodular matrix ($\det(U) = \pm 1$) and solve for $a,b,c,d$. If there exists a solution where all the entries are integers then the two lattices are related by a rotation operation.

**EDIT:** To make it clear, here is an example of two lattices that are not simple rotations of each other but the checks pass:

1. $\mathcal{B}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \Lambda_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$ and
2. $\mathcal{B}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \Lambda_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{e}_x & \hat{e}_y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$.

I think this should work but it is very inefficient. I think there should be an efficient solution for this. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Gram matrices for your two lattices, then the quadratic forms they define. Gauss reduce both.

NO EIGENVECTORS

[PDF](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/ntii/chap4.pdf)

online calculator:
http://www.numbertheory.org/php/reduceneg.html

Given a symmetric matrix of integers
$$
G = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr}
v \cdot v & v \cdot w \\
w \cdot v & w \cdot w
\end{array}
\right) =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr}
e  & f \\
f & g 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we get a quadratic form 
$$ h(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,  $$
where here $a=e, b = 2f, c = g.$
Notation
$$ \langle a,b,c \rangle $$
refers to this form. Your form is automatically positive.
[Gauss reduction of a binary quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form#Reduction_and_class_numbers) is very fast, accomplished by a finite number of of these mappings:
$$ \langle a,b,c \rangle \mapsto \langle c,-b,a \rangle,$$ or
$$ \langle a,b,c \rangle \mapsto \langle a, b + 2 t a, c + bt + a t^2 \rangle.$$
For this choice we take $t$ so that $|b+2ta| \leq a.$

The final result is a Gauss reduced form $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ which means:
$$a > 0, c \geq a, -a < b \leq a;  $$ also
if $a=c$ then $b \geq 0.$

If your lattices are $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalent they will create identical reduced quadratic forms. If they are not quite equivalent ( for example one basis is the same as the basis of the other, but in reversed order) the (reduced)forms will be "opposite" $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and $\langle a,-b,c \rangle$

My favorite book on this is Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms*. It would be easier (and cheaper) to find a paperback reprint of  L. E. Dickson, *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, originally 1929.

Buell:

[image]

Comment: Will - Just to confirm the Gram matrix is $\Lambda^T \cdot \Lambda$ and the Gauss reduction is the reduced row echelon form? I use matlab so this function here - https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html? I am adding a case where lattices are **not** related to each other by simple rotation to clearly state the problem definition. Thanks!

Comment: I might not have the right background to understand your answer. So, I am using the following steps: 1) $G_1 = \Lambda_1^T \cdot \Lambda_1$ to get the Gram matrix of lattice 1. (similarily, I will get $G_2$). 2) To get the quadratic forms, I should get the eigen-vectors of $G_1$ and $G_2$??. **I am reading some online resources on these concepts but could you explain the reasoning behind your answer?** Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details and references, Will. I will go through the resources. In the meantime, **could this be extended to lattices in 3D? I will end up with a $3\times3$ Gram matrix and a ternary quadratic form?** Also, my basis vectors need not be integers. I think in this I can just multiply them to make them integers as long as they are rational. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: somewhat related (and currently unanswered): [How should I restrict the points considered in each hexagonal lattice to correctly count all unique near-coincident lattices? Part II (finite sizes)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3669788/284619)

Answer (score 2):

Similar Matrices have identical [smith normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). If you have Matrices $A$, $B$ with SNF's 
$$
U_AAV_A = U_BBV_B
$$
you can transform lattice points and their solutions from $A$ to $B$ and back.