# Correctly count all unique near-coincident hexagonal lattice pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My earlier question *How should I restrict the points considered in each hexagonal lattice to correctly count all unique near-coincident lattices?* turns out to have an [excellent and instructive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669744/284619), primarily because I'd left out part of the question I'd planned on posting.

Please see [How should I restrict the points considered in each hexagonal lattice to correctly count all unique near-coincident lattices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3669461/284619) for the setup to this question, but now with the added constraint that the absolute values of the indices $(i, j), (k, l)$ will be limited to some finite size with a parameter $n_{max}$ such that $|i| \le n_{max}$, $|j| \le n_{max}$ and $|i+j| \le n_{max}$ which forms a hexagonally bound array of points when $x = a \left(i + \frac{1}{2} j\right)$ and $y = a \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} j$.

**A further constraint for my problem** is that $a_2/a_1$ is irrational *and fixed*. This is the reason for the finite $\delta$. For a small $n_{max}$ there are usually no solutions, but opening up $\delta$ to say 0.01 allows for some *near-coincident* lattice matchings; we're essentially stretching or compressing the 2nd lattice to "make it coincident" with the first.

---

**Question:** How should I restrict the points considered in each hexagonal lattice to correctly count all unique near-coincident lattices when $(i, j)$ are limited by $n_{max}$ as described above?

I know I should restrict my search to a pie-shaped segment of all points in each of the two lattices, perhaps a 30° slice of one against a 60° slice of the other, but I haven't been able to convince myself that this guess is mathematically sound.

---

Example of a proper coincident lattice: $(i, j), (k, l) = (5, 4), (2, 3)$ with $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = \sqrt{\frac{61}{19}}$ and $n_{max} = 16$ with cuts at $0 \le \theta_{ij} < 60°$ and $0 \le \theta_{kl} < 30°$. This finds exactly one coincidence point. *Are these angle restrictions correct to find all near-coincident solutions?* Ignoring solutions with lowest common denominators $LCD(i, j, k, l) > 1$ will help avoid some redundancies.

[image: example of coincident lattice with angle restrictions]

Comment: By reducing the bounds for lattice size, we merely filter those values for the $a$ ratio that are too far from any legal exact lattice.  Since there are still uncountably many real numbers within any neighborhood of a particular number, this isn't going to help much.

Comment: @DanUznanski this is extremely helpful because it shows me how poorly I'm doing explaining the problem! I'd forgotten to say that for the problem I want to solve $a_2/a_1$ is both irrational *and fixed*. Given those and a small $\delta$ and small $n_{max}$ there are frequently zero or just a few solutions.

Comment: @DanUznanski I've edited the question accordingly. It's past midnight here; I'll have to leave this as-is until morning, but I think with the added explanation it should be clear. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Help with proper tagging is appreciated!

Comment: **oh**.  Okay this is a different problem and indeed warrants an answer in a different field entirely!  This appears to be a problem near [tag:continued-fractions], which is the field we usually use to describe fractions that iteratively approach a target number, keeping the denominator as small as possible.  For my $\pi$ example on the other question I have simply used an exhaustive search, trying every possible ratio with a given denominator and then proceeding to the next, but I bet there's a better answer if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @DanUznanski I've added an additional figure to highlight that my question is about angular restrictions.

Comment: Possible connection with Goldberg-Coxeter contruction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg%E2%80%93Coxeter_construction)

Comment: @DanUznanski I've posted an answer that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pick points geometrically you are *working too hard*.

here's how it's really done, with the example of finding a decent match for a size ratio of $x = \pi$.

In this we will be iterating over the [Loeschain numbers](http://oeis.org/A003136), which is equivalent to considering points in order of euclidean distance from the origin.

We'll start with $a_2=1$, using $k=1$ and $\ell=0$.  We now find lower and upper $a_{1-}$, $a_{1+}$ and corresponding $i_-,j_-, i_+, j_+$ by starting at $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ and $\lceil x^2 \rceil$ and going down and up respectively until we land on Loeschian numbers.  Then $p = a_{1-}/a_2$ and $q = a_{1+}/a_2$ are our current best approximations -- well, the squares of the best approximations; working with integers is less of a pain in general.

Repeatedly: increment $a_2$ to the next Loeschian number.  Calculate $a_2x^2$ again, and also $a_2p$ and $a_2q$.  Starting at $\lfloor a_2x^2 \rfloor$ and $\lceil a_2x^2 \rceil$, again go down and up respectively to find Loeschian numbers... but if you reach $a_2p$ or $a_2q$ before that happens, give up: something earlier worked better.  On the other hand, if you do find one, then you can update $p$ or $q$ as appropriate.

This can go on forever, so long as it's never true that $a_2x^2$ is itself a Loeschian number; in that case you've found an exact match.

---

So, for $\pi$:

- $\pi^2 \approx 9.9$, so our starting point is $p=9$, $q=12$
- $3\pi^2 \approx 29.6$, and we find $3\cdot9 < 28 < 3\pi^2 < 31 < 3\cdot12$, so now $p=28/3$, $q=31/3$
- $4\pi^2 \approx 39.5$, $4\frac{28}{3} < 39 < 4\pi^2 < 4\frac{31}{3}$ -- this time, we don't find a better upper bound, so only $p$ changes, to $\frac{39}{4}$.
- $7\pi^2 \approx 69.1$, and in this case we don't find any thing that improves the situation.
- Proceeding in this fashion we get $q = \frac{91}{9}$, $q = \frac{121}{12}$, $p = \frac{127}{13}$, $q=\frac{129}{13}$, $p = \frac{157}{16}$, $q=\frac{208}{21}$, and $q=\frac{247}{25}$, and so on.

Not all the numbers we get are optimal: $\frac{157}{16}$ isn't as good as $\frac{129}{13}$, but it is on the low side instead of the high side so we get to keep it for now to keep us on track.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Once I've had my coffee I'll compare this to the procedure I've got running at the moment. Right now I'm not confident that my housekeeping is correct, and I may be double counting the same match multiple times by "discovering" additional points in the same coincident lattice and not recognizing them as such, while at the same time not missing any.

Comment: just fyi I've added a second bounty to [Determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved my problem but I don't know how to offer a formal proof for this.

It's clear that it is sufficient to include only the points in $0 \le \theta \le 30°$ from each lattice in order to find all possible lengths in each.

Each lattice is 6-fold symmetric so rotations from one lattice to the other are only unique within for example $-30° \le R \le 30°$  range, and every rotation at $+R$ will have a mirror point at $-R$

So use points in each lattice within $0 \le \theta \le 30°$ and for every rotation $\mod(R, 30°) \ne 0$ include a second rotation at $-R$.

[image: hexagonal lattice]

plot: https://pastebin.com/fnxGV3Yc

Comment: You will note that every point in the $30°$ wedge has $0 \le j \le i$; searching this segment is equivalent to trying Loeschian numbers, generating them using `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)`.  The conceit of considering angles and all that is actually way overkill for this problem once you've reduced it to number crunching like this.

Comment: @DanUznanski thanks for the insight; now that I have a picture to work with I can revisit your [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669744/284619) and try to look at this as a mathematician would. Please feel free to add a math-based answer here, even a short one. It would likely be the accepted answer and more useful than this one.

Comment: @DanUznanski I'd gotten sidetracked but back on it now, and I've just asked [Test if a point on a hexagonal lattice falls on a specified superlattice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696925/284619)